# Grouping the batch in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this data:

```
Id|rank|   date
------------------
1 | 7  |07/08/2015
1 | 7  |09/08/2015
1 | 8  |16/08/2015
1 | 8  |17/08/2015
1 | 7  |19/08/2015
1 | 7  |15/08/2015
2 | 7  |01/08/2015
2 | 7  |02/08/2015
2 | 8  |16/08/2015
2 | 8  |17/08/2015
2 | 7  |26/08/2015
2 | 7  |28/08/2015
```

My desired solution is

```
1 | 7  |07/08/2015 |1
1 | 7  |09/08/2015 |1
1 | 8  |16/08/2015 |2
1 | 8  |17/08/2015 |2
1 | 7  |19/08/2015 |3
1 | 7  |15/08/2015 |3
2 | 7  |01/08/2015 |4
2 | 7  |02/08/2015 |4
2 | 8  |16/08/2015 |5
2 | 8  |17/08/2015 |5
2 | 7  |26/08/2015 |6
2 | 7  |28/08/2015 |6
```

i.e for each block of id and rank I want to add the new column and updated the same.

Comment: what is the logic behind the numbering ?

Comment: it the combination of batch id ,rank i.e I am trying to achieve a minimum of date on the basis of new column. Here for same ID  7 is repeated in 2 batches so i have to get the minimum of date of each batch...for instance for 1 st batch o/p would be 1 | 7  |07/08/2015 |1

1 | 8  |16/08/2015 |2

1 | 7  |15/08/2015 |3

Comment: @user2941762 Can you describe the logic precisely? Say, for ID = 1 and rank = 7 why dates 07/08/2015 and 09/08/2015 has value of number equal to 1 and 19/08/2015 and 15/08/2015 dates for the same ID/rank has value of 3? I see no logiс here....

Comment: Yes the logic is weird but this is the requirement..I have tried using nested while loops its taking too much time

Comment: Instead of saying your logic is weird, **tell us** what the logic is. We don't know it unless you write it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is dense_rank.

See if the following query helps.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE 
  ( 
     id INT,rank INT,data DATETIME 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @temp 
VALUES      (1,7,'08/07/2015'), 
            (1,7,'08/09/2015'), 
            (1,8,'08/16/2015'), 
            (1,8,'08/17/2015'), 
            (1,7,'08/19/2015'), 
            (1,7,'08/15/2015'), 
            (2,7,'08/01/2015'), 
            (2,7,'08/02/2015'), 
            (2,8,'08/16/2015'), 
            (2,8,'08/17/2015'), 
            (2,7,'08/26/2015'), 
            (2,7,'08/28/2015') 

SELECT *,Dense_rank() 
           OVER( 
             ORDER BY id, rank) AS New_Column 
FROM   @Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic what I have tried and it is running successfully .Thanks everyone.

```
create table #temp
(
       iden int identity(1,1),
       ID int,
       [rank] int,
       [date] date,
       dr_id int,
       rownum_id int,
       grouprecord int
)


Insert into #temp(id,rank,date)
select 1 , 7  ,'07/08/2015'
union all select  1 , 7  ,'09/08/2015'
union all select  1 , 8  ,'08/16/2015'
union all select  1 , 8  ,'08/17/2015'
union all select  1 , 7  ,'08/19/2015'
union all select  1 , 7  ,'08/15/2015'
union all select  2 , 7  ,'08/01/2015'
union all select  2 , 7  ,'08/02/2015'
union all select  2 , 8  ,'08/16/2015'
union all select  2 , 8  ,'08/17/2015'
union all select  2 , 7  ,'08/26/2015'
union all select  2 , 7  ,'08/28/2015'


update t1
set dr_id = t2.rn
from #temp t1 inner join
(select  iden, dense_rank() over(order by id) as rn from #temp) t2
on t1.iden = t2.iden


update t1
set rownum_id = t2.rn
from #temp t1 inner join
(select  iden, row_number() over(partition by dr_id order by id) as rn from #temp) t2
on t1.iden = t2.iden




select *,row_number() over(order by iden)rn into #temp1 from
(             
                     select t2.* 
              from #temp t1 inner join #temp t2
              on (t1.dr_id = t2.dr_id or t2.dr_id = (t1.dr_id +1) ) and ( t1.rank<>t2.rank or t2.dr_id = (t1.dr_id +1) )
              and t2.iden = t1.iden  + 1
)a





declare @id int,@miniden int,@maxiden int,@maxid int
set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(iden) from #temp

while exists(select 1 from #temp1 where rn = @id)
begin
       Select @miniden = iden from #temp1
       where rn = @id

       Select @maxiden = iden from #temp1
       where rn = @id+1

       update #temp
       set grouprecord = @id +1
       where iden between @miniden and @maxiden

IF(@maxiden IS NULL)
BEGIN 
       Update #temp
       set grouprecord = @id +1
       where iden between @miniden and @maxid
END

       set @id = @id + 1
       SET @miniden =NULL
       SET @maxiden = NULL
end

UPDATE #TEMP
SET GROUPRECORD = 1
WHERE GROUPRECORD IS NULL
select * from #temp
```